# Qt5: error: 'WA_LockPortraitOrientation' is not a member of 'Qt'

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, qwidget, qtgui

I'm trying to compile a Qt4/Symbian project to Qt5, while preserving support for Qt4/Symbian.

Currently the `MainWindow::setOrientation` auto-generated boilerplate function is giving me trouble.

It gives me these compiler errors:

```
error: 'WA_LockPortraitOrientation' is not a member of 'Qt'
error: 'WA_LockLandscapeOrientation' is not a member of 'Qt'
error: 'WA_AutoOrientation' is not a member of 'Qt'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, those were removed in Qt 5 as you noted yourself.

The reason is that these are Symbian-only features and such things just confuse the Qt users if they only work on a certain platform, especially if that platform is not even supported by Qt 5, inherently.

The corresponding gerrit change can be found in here:

https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,11280

You need to change these lines

```
#if QT_VERSION < 0x040702
    // Qt < 4.7.2 does not yet have the Qt::WA_*Orientation attributes
```

to these:

```
#if (QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(4, 7, 2)) || (QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 0, 0))
    // Qt < 4.7.2 does not yet have the Qt::WA_*Orientation attributes
    // Qt 5 has removed them.
```

---

The nice way for conditionally allowing certain features based on the Qt version would be this:

```
#if (QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(4, 7, 2)) || (QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 0, 0))
...
#endif
```

It is cleaner and nicer than hard-coding hex values. It is also the recommended way that [existing Qt modules follow](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport/source/d5658bd0ced4a1eb0703d3cb1b566025d610fbdd%3asrc/serialport/qserialportinfo_unix.cpp#L300), like QtSerialPort.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by changing these line:

```
#if QT_VERSION < 0x040702
    // Qt < 4.7.2 does not yet have the Qt::WA_*Orientation attributes
```

to these:

```
#if (QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(4, 7, 2)) || (QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 0, 0))
    // Qt < 4.7.2 does not yet have the Qt::WA_*Orientation attributes
    // Qt 5 has removed them.
```